# Prove that function is multiplicative

Tags: multiplicative-function

Prove that if $f(n)$ is multiplicative, so is $g(n) = \sum\limits_{d/n}f(d)$.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ such that $m\wedge n=1$, then notice that $d\vert nm$ if and only $d=d_1d_2$ with $d_1\vert m$ and $d_2\vert n$. Therefore, one has:
\begin{align}
g(mn)&=\sum_{d\vert nm}f(d)\\
&=\sum_{d_1\vert m,d_2\vert n}f(d_1d_2)\\
&=\sum_{d_1\vert m,d_2\vert n}f(d_1)f(d_2)\tag{1}\\
&=\left(\sum_{d_1\vert m}f(d_1)\right)\left(\sum_{d_2\vert n}f(d_2)\right)\\
&=g(m)g(n)
\end{align}
Where $(1)$ follows from the multiplicativity of $f$. Whence the result.

Comment: Why You have assumed that  $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ ?

Comment: My definition of an arithmetic map is $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, but if yours is with $\mathbb{Z}$, then just replace $\mathbb{N}^2$ with $\mathbb{Z}^2$, the proof works the same.

Comment: Ok, and by saying $(m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ such that $m\wedge n=1$ You wanted to state that m and n are relatively prime? There is a small typo in last sum there should be $n$.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry if this is not a conventional notation. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the factorization of $n$ is given by
$$ n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_{k}^{\alpha_k} \tag{1} $$
There is a bijection between the set of divisors of $n$ and the elements of $[0,\alpha_1]\times\ldots\times[0,\alpha_k]$.
By exploiting the multiplicativity of $f$, we get that:
$$ (f*1)(n)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{d\mid n}f(d) = \prod_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{\alpha=0}^{\alpha_k}f(p_j^\alpha) =\prod_{j=1}^{k}(f*1)(p_j^{\alpha_k})\tag{2}$$
If $a$ and $b$ are coprime numbers, the sets of prime divisors of $a$ and $b$ are disjoint and the set of prime divisors of $ab$ is just the union of them. By $(2)$ it follows that
$$ (f*1)(ab) = (f*1)(a)\cdot (f*1)(b)\tag{3} $$
as wanted.